# Checking, if Model C is related with any Model B related with Model A

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I know that it seems complicated, but I'll explain it.

- I have 3 models, let's call them A, B and C.
- All of them can be related to others via Many-to-Many relationships.

I want to check, if Model C is related with any Model B, which is related to my model.

I want to check it by "name" column of Model C instead of ID.

Comment: just do a (inner) join and see if any records are returned?

Comment: @NDM: I don't quite understand, how to do that. Also, inner join, if done on pivot table, searches by IDs, so I must do another query to get my Model C's ID.
I wanted to get specific answer.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM model_a JOIN model_a.name = model_b.name_of_a;` if that returns any rows, there are A's who have links to B's

Comment: @NDM: You haven't read the whole question. It's Laravel 4, so I want to do this with Eloquent style (as tagged), and raw SELECT deosn't fit there, because Eloquent has join methods. It's Many-to-Many, so it's done via pivot table, hence no model_b.name_of_a

Comment: what do you mean to check if related ? You mean if Model A has some entries of the type Model B (for example, check if Post has Comments ?)

Comment: @Gadoma: More like: if any of User's Group has specific Permission.

Comment: well you just tagged some technology, but never mention it in your entire question... you also tagged MySQL so.... you should be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

after some digging and asking around on irc it turned out that my previous approach was not at all a correct way to deal with this issue :)

Kudos to @Oddman and @Kindari for great input into the discussion - as suggested, to test whether two "many-to-many models" A and B are related you can use the lists method  (Illuminate\Support\Collection)

```
in_array($b->id, $a->related()->lists('b_id'))
```

If next you want to check by 'name' if C is related to B, can you provide details on how is this column used in the relationship - do you have it present in the pivot table ? If so, maybe you can try the below - but it is only a wild guess of mine here...

```
in_array($c->name, $b->related()->lists('c_name'))
```

Apart from the above, you can always do a raw sql query with appropriate joins and it's a sure way to get it working. You can start off where @NDM suggests.

Surely a good thing to check out the docs as well:
http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many
http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: It's not correct. It's could be used for getting, if my Model A has Model C. No, I want to check, if any of Model B related to my Model A i s related to specific Model C.

Comment: I edited my answer in reference to your comment. If this is still not the concept you need - paste your models' code in your question or here - paste.laravel.com - and submit a link in your OP - regards

Comment: So, do I need to iterate over array and check, if that's it?

Comment: previous answer was not correct at all, check the current edit :)

Comment: Problem is, that I don't want to care about B's name. It looks like I must know the particaular B. Problem is, that I want to check, if C is related to ANY of A's Bs.

Comment: then you'd have to use the "id way" twice I guess

Answer (score 0):

How about just using couple of inner joins? The good part with Eloquent is that you can always use [Laravel's DB query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) as a part of the Eloquent model to handle more complicated cases as Eloquent is build upon Query builder.

```
    $a = A::select('a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name, c.id, b.name')
                    ->join('a_b_pivot', 'a.id', '=', 'b.a_id')
                    ->join('b_c_pivot', 'b.id', '=', 'c.b_id')
                    ->join('b', 'a_b_pivot.b_id', '=', 'b.id')
                    ->join('c', 'b_c_pivot.c_id', '=', 'c.id')
                    ->where('c.name', '=', $name);
```

Probably not the most efficient way but should work and should be more efficient than walking through the models and loading everything as models etc.

Just make sure you mention all fields with the table names or it doesn't work. Depending on what model you want back from the query, you could also start the query from C:: or B:: and tweak it according to that.

Other useful thing is probably using eager loading as a part of the query or ->load('b,c) after you get the results.

And don't forget you can [create query scope](http://ifonlyiknewthat.com/laravel/laravel-4-orm-query-scope/) out of this so it's easy to reuse anywhere in the code :)